# What does "wind up" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

In this sentence, what does *wind up* mean?

> But the honest man you don't have to buy - he winds up costing you nothing.
>
> Source: [Goodreads Quotes - Harold Robbins, *The Carpetbaggers*](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7495241-every-man-has-his-price-for-some-it-s-money-for)

Comment: "Wind up" is just a synonym for "end up" here.

Comment: Excellent question.  Not sure how it is off topic. The meaning of "wind up" usually indicates to arrive at a destination or how things end.  For example, "If you go straight down this street you wind up [arrive] at the grocery store."  In Robbins' sentence, when you arrive at a future time you will find that an honest man cost you nothing.